# New to Titan db, help installing titan db

Tags: hadoop, titan

I am new to Titan db and I have been reading the documentation in this website:    http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/0.5.4/ I really could not find much documentations on installing Titan db, can I install it on my windows 7 or do I need to install it on a Virtual machine that runs on Linux?

Is this the only download I need to get started? Titan 0.5.4 with Hadoop 2 (signature). https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/wiki/Downloads ?

Do I also need to install hadoop or will the link above i provided will install it as well?

Comment: If you decide to go for a Titan / HBase install on Linux, this article should help you to get started: http://blog.trackerbird.com/content/setting-up-titan-1-0-apache-hbase/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Titan distribution you mentioned generally has what you need to get started.  I'm not sure what you mean by "installing titan" because how you set it up is highly dependent on what you plan to do with it.  If you are just playing around in the Titan Gremlin Console, just unapackage the Titan distribution you mentioned and start it with the included `gremlin.sh` file (or in the case of windows `gremlin.bat`).  If you plan to use a backend like hbase or cassandra, you probably need to have those up and running first - check their documentation to understand how that works.  The same could be said of the indexing backends like elasticsearch.  In short, your question is a bit too general to answer with real specifics.

I would recommend that you spend some more time reviewing the documentation you referenced to make sure you understand the Titan architecture and approach.  If you skipped [Getting Started](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/0.5.4/getting-started.html) or didn't fully understand that, I would re-read it and try out the examples.  If that's a bit too much you might even consider stepping back to just pure Gremlin and trying the [Getting Started](https://github.com/tinkerpop/gremlin/wiki/Getting-Started) docs there.

Comment: there is a bug in the .bat file so windows user can't start it. See http://learntitandb.blogspot.be/2016/01/titan-db-tutorial-1-download-and-run.html